# 'Expo not defined' in React Native

Tags: react-native, webpack, android-emulator, expo

I am working on an App in RN and when trying to run either an Android Emulator or Webpack the error 'Expo not defined' pops up. I have had my instructor look over the code and he hasn't quite figured it out either. The first time I was able to get it working by restarting my computer as well as re-installing node-modules. Any advice? Here is a screenshot.[Expo not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMUZY.png)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have some code in MainComponent.js that calls `Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight` - you should remove that

Comment: What's interesting is that all my classmates have identical code (or nearly identical as its the same app) and they don't have these issues.

Comment: i guess "nearly identical" is the catch there -- if it's not exactly identical that could be the problem! also it depends on the sdk version your classmates are using. `Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight` used to be a way to access this data but now you need to access it from importing `expo-constants` (go to https://snack.expo.io/ and look at the new-app example you see when it first loads to see it)

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing Expo in top of file?

```
import Expo from 'expo';
```

Can you install expo again?

```
npm install expo
```

Answer (score 0):

if u r compiling the code on web then ofc it will show error on expo being undefined but check that app on mobile running expo app it will run there without any error . 
Hope it solved your problem